# Detect/Alert if an HTTP proxy is running

Tags: proxy, adware

I mistakenly installed 7Zip a couple of weeks ago and got a pile of garbage i didn't want.  It was all easy enough to remove.  However, today I discovered that browersafeguard.exe was running, and after killing it, my browsers stopped working.  Browsersafeguard.exe was acting as a proxy for http/and https.

While in this case, browsersafeguard.exe is reasonably reputable, it could have been a lot worse.

Is there a simple monitor, tray program, browser plugin, or homepage trick for windows that can detect if a proxy is running?

I only need a notification, not an all out blocker - I use fiddler regularly.